# Loki shows wrong timestamp in Grafana

Tags: grafana-loki

Currently, Loki displays the wrong time in Grafana. We've tried various solutions, however the time has become unusable as it's so off.  I've been looking through documentation, and Grafana, but so far, haven't found a working solution.

Example:

Time show by Loki 2023-03-27 20:21:19

Timestamp: "timestamp":"2023-03-25T20:42:51.283144Z"

Time should show: 2023-03-25 16:42:51

Solution tried:

```
    scrapeConfigs: |
      - job_name: loki
          use_incoming_timestamp: false
    pipeline_stages:
      - json:
          expressions:
            time: timestamp
      - timestamp:
          source: time
          format: 2006-01-02T15:04:05-07:00
```

Any help on this would be much appreciated!